# Get Disk Powershell Force Yes to complete partitioning

Tags: powershell, automation, remote-access

I have this powershell script that's meant to automatically add a disk,partition and label it. However when i run it it does completely automate the whole process because it needs "yes" to be clicked then it completes the whole formatting process as well. Is there a line I can add it my script to force it to say yes and does the formatting as i want to run it remotely

```
Get-Disk 
Initialize-Disk 3 -PartitionStyle MBR 
New-Partition -DiskNumber 3 -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize
Format-Volume -DriveLetter Z -FileSystem NTFS 
Set-Volume -DriveLetter Z -NewFileSystemLabel "SystemDrive" quick-Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Seems like a few line breaks and/or `|` are missing from your script. You probably need `Initialize-Disk ... -Confirm:$false`

Comment: Dont know how to add the code quotes in a reply but I do have the initialize disk at the start of the script and the -confirm false at the end

Comment: Yes, but `Get-Disk`, `Initialize-Disk`, `New-Partition`, `Format-Volume` and `Set-Volume` are 5 *separate* commands, so throwing `-confirm:$false` at the very end only applies to the last one.

Comment: so I probably need to add the last line at the end of each command to see if it applies the changes to all ?

Comment: Usually `-Confirm:$false` is only required for cmdlets that make *changes* to things, so my guess would be the last 3 or 4 commands

Comment: (my code is not showing in the code quotes )I have been able to make it work by amending my code to something like this: `$Script = @"
 Select Disk 7
 Online Disk
Attributes Disk Clear ReadOnly
Clean
 Convert GPT
 Create Partition Primary
 Format FS=NTFS Quick
 Assign
 "@
 $Result = $Script | DiskPart